# How do I enable tap to click on my Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad buttons weren't working too well so I was in activity overview and I turned off "tap to click". Now I can't click anything. Is there a way to turn it back on?
I am new to computers and I don't know anything. Can I solve this using the terminal? Please help.

Comment: You should still be able to click "regularly", ie not by tapping, but by pressing the touchpad left bottom until it clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solved your problem already. Just for future reference:

1. Start the Terminal by the Overview:
   Press <kbd>Win/Super</kbd> and type `terminal` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Then type this into the terminal:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true`